# Definition of Sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

The last property that makes a presheaf a sheaf says: Let $U$ be an open set in $X$ such that $U=\bigcup_{j\in J}U_j$.

If $aj \in \mathscr{F}(U_j)$, $j \in J$, satisfies

$\rho_{U_j(U_i\cap U_j)}(a_j)=\rho_{U_i(U_j\cap U_i)}(a_i)$, $i,j \in J$,

then there exists $a \in \mathscr{F}(U)$ such that $a_j=\rho_{UU_j}(a)$.

My question is as follows, $\forall j\in J, \exists a_j \in \mathscr{F}(U_j)$ such that, $\forall i,j \in J, \rho_{U_j(U_i\cap U_j)}(a_j)=\rho_{U_i(U_j\cap U_i)}(a_i)$, then there...

How can there be both variations on $j$ at the same time? It seems to me that the second variation of $j$ (together with the variation of $i$) in $J$ doesn't happen at all.

Comment: Your question is unclear but I assume you ask why there are two "for all" quantifiers with $j$. But there is only one. If you want to write the sheaf condition by formulas, it should go "$\exists\{a_j \in \mathscr{F}(U_j)\}_{j \in J}$ such that ..." In other words, the first $j$ is a set index and its scope ends just there. You can use another letter instead.

Comment: It seems to me that the first "for all" is subordinate to the second "for all".

Comment: As I've said, there is only one quantifier if you write the definition correctly.

Comment: It would be something like: If $\alpha \in \{\rho_{U_i(U_i\cap U_j)}(\mathscr{F}(U_i))\cap \rho_{U_j(U_i\cap U_j)}(\mathscr{F}(U_j)) \mid (i,j)\in J \times J \}$, then there $\exists a \in \mathscr{F}(U)$ such that $\rho_{UU_i}(a)=\alpha$???